# How do I add a new Object to a Array, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I add `newObject` to my array `shapeArr`? 
Do I need to add a for loop?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            ul{ list-style-type:none;}
            div{ width:300px; height:200px; background-color:#0066cc; }
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="placeholder"></ul>
        <a href="#" id="btn">Add</a>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function add(){

                function draw(){

                    var template = document.createElement("li");
                    template.innerHTML = "<div></div><a href='#' class='update'>Update</a>";                

                    document.getElementById("placeholder").appendChild(template);
                }

                var newObject = new draw();

                var shapeArr = [];

            }

            var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
            btn.addEventListener("click", add, false);

        </script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is too broad to be answered accurately. Why don't you reduce your code to the parts relevant to the question and further explain what it is you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `push()` method of the JavaScript Array to add new elements to the end:

```
var newObject = new draw();
var shapeArr  = [];

// add the new Object
shapeArr.push(newObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

```
shapeArr.push(newObject);
```